# Spark Data frames load into driver

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Imagine we have some

```
val hiveTableDataFrame: DataFrame
```

And I want to stream rows of this data frame into my driver program. The thing is the `hiveTableDataFrame` is too large and I cannot use `hiveTableDataFrame.collect()`. Is there a way to read the data from the dataframe by chunks?